# ¿Por qué me tira errores una petición GET con Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular

Estoy haciendo una API muy simple la cual estoy verificando con postman que funcione correctamente, tengo algo llamado `obtener_usuarios` lo cual me regresa un arreglo de todos los usuarios en la DB. Pero al ponerlo en un servicio de Angular 6 no funciona.

[Leí en StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50845983/error-cant-resolve-rxjs-add-operator-map) que RxJS cambió la manera de utilizar el operador map, entonces ahora lo estoy importando [de la manera como se indica](https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/).

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, HttpModule } from "@angular/http";
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsuariosService {

  usuarios : any[] = [];

  constructor( public http: Http ) { }

  cargarTodos() {
    let url = "http://localhost:8888/rest/index.php/usuarios/obtener_usuarios";
    this.http.get(url).pipe(
      map( (resp) => resp.json() )
    ).subscribe( (data)  => {
      console.log(data);
    }));
  }

}
```

Los errores que me arroja la consola del explorador son muchísimos (como 300 líneas):

```
core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[UsuariosService -> Http]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[UsuariosService -> Http]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Http
```

Este proyecto de angular es nuevo, realmente no tiene mucho. Sólo 3 páginas con puro HTML, no he escrito nada de JS.

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.10.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 6.1.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.3.2
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

Antes de iniciar el proyecto node me pidió actualizar con `sudo npm i -g npm`. Mi versión actual es `6.4.1`.

Answer (score 2):

Hace falta agregar la importación de `HttpClientModule` a tu `app.module`

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

y agregarla a

```
@NgModule({
  ....
  imports: [
    ....,
    HttpClientModule
  ]
],
```